# Android App crashes when I change Location permission from settings react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, android-permissions

I have a problem with React Native Permissions on Android. If the user changes Location Permission from the Device setting while the app is running the app crashes right after that.

I search on the internet for a while I found someone who said this is a normal android behavior to restart the app after permissions changes but there is some app out there that manages to avoid this.

did anyone out there know how to handle this?

ask the user to allow Location permission code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      ({coords}) => {
        let position = {
          latitude: coords.latitude,
          longitude: coords.longitude,
          latitudeDelta: latitudeDelta,
          longitudeDelta: longitudeDelta,
        };
        setLocation(position);
      },
      error => {
        if (enabled && Platform.OS === 'android') {
          return false;
        } else {
          Alert.alert(t('Access Denied'), error.message);
        }
      },
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: false,
        timeout: 10000,
        maximumAge: 0,
      },
    );
  }, []);
```

Comment: Cath the exception that lets your app crash.

Comment: how to do that there are no actual error shown on logs or anywhere

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For both platforms IOS and Android, the application will be restarted if you change permissions settings from the OS settings. You can't bypass it. For better permission handling I can advise you to use https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions which provides an abstraction over both platforms with values:

```js
type PermissionStatus = 'unavailable' | 'denied' | 'limited' | 'granted' | 'blocked';
```